# Appium inspector for iOS app cannot detect UIView inside UIStackView

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios, xcuitest

I'm iOS developer currently exploring automation testing with robot framework and Appium. I notice that Appium inspector (or maybe XCTest framework in general) cannot detect UIView element even if I put `accessibilityIdentifier` in it.

Below is the view hierarrchy:

[image: IB with UIStackView]

[image: IB with UIStackView]

I add `accessibilityIdentifier` with type string and value `departure_button` on `fromView` view since it is the view which hold the `tapGesture`.

Below is the Appium inspector
[image]

Well, I can select the first label to perform the click and get the same effect. But, is it normal behaviour?

Comment: Hi, Try to set isEnableAccessibility true by code OR enable in property window.

Comment: @arulchristopher Ok, I'll try

Comment: @SetoElkahfi have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501143/accessibility-for-controls-in-stack-view), it helped me. Shortly speaking you have to check that parent doesn't appear to be accessibility element otherwise accessibility children elements are ignored.